# Login local , login synchronous

Tags: cisco, switch, packet-tracer, ssh

I dont understand what those two comands mean when im enabling **ssh**
on Vty-line.
Can someone please explaim me please **what**those comand do and **why** i need to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`login local`  tells the router to use the local database for authentication.  You add account to the local database using the `username` command.

`logging synchronous` (not `login synchronous`) formats the CLI output so that when information is displayed on the console, it doesn't affect the CLI prompt. After console output is shown, the router re-displays the CLI prompt to make entering commands easier.

Comment: Isn't it `logging synchronous`?

Comment: Um, well...yes of course. Answered without engaging brain. Thanks for the correction Ron and Mike.

Comment: We got your back...